# how i can get audio from localPeer andRemotePeer if i use addTransceiver?[edit]

Tags: webrtc, openwebrtc

what i try

to implenet this steps as possiabe as i can from what i understanding and what i reading and what other people move through from question problem that what i can gather and implementing my code AS They do

what i expect

every thing working fine and gathering more knowledge about using webRTC for further project

steps i move through

```
 1- addTransceiver on localPeer
 
 2-getTransceiver On remote Peer
```

so this my code 2 peers of connection

```
yourConn = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
yourConn2 = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
```

and i'm stuck here after i do addTranceiver and reverse direction in remotePeer to sendrecv

yourConn.addTransceiver(streams.getAudioTracks()[0]);

how i can after that obtain audio from remotePeer?

Comment: @PeterSmith cab u help

Comment: @jib
can anyone help ?

Comment: This question is too long and too difficult to understand. Ideally, post a complete example that others can try. Then ask one question.

Comment: so should i create a new question with less answer and more example?

Comment: @Luz what about that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i will answer my question

what i did and working fine is to usning event in ontrackEvent and accessing the transceiver on both lacal and remote with

for remote peer

and for sending just reverse the direction and send what u need

```
yourConn2.ontrack = await e => {
  /* do something with e.track */

//receive here
   if (e.transceiver.receiver.track) {
          remoteVideo = document.getElementById("wbrtcremote");
          transceiversRemotePeer = new 
          MediaStream([e.transceiver.receiver.track]);
          remoteVideo.srcObject = transceiversRemotePeer  
          }

   //send here
  e.transceiver.direction = 'sendrecv';
  await e.transceiver.sender.replaceTrack(localstream);
};
```

for more details about how u can do it and why u need to reverse direction to
e.transceiver.direction = 'sendrecv';

that because on the receiver side(yourConn2), the direction is "downgraded" from sendrecv to recvonly because by default this transceiver is not configured to send anything back from receiverPc(yourConn2) to senderPc(yourConn).

After all, it was just created in response to setRemoteDescription(offer). To fix this, you "upgrade" the direction to sendrecv and set a track to send.
like so as above

```
e.transceiver.direction = 'sendrecv';
```

e.transceiver.sender.replaceTrack(localStream.getAudioTracks()[0]).then(() => {

```
    });
```

If you do this prior to creating the local SDP answer on receiverPc, you should be able to achieve "sendrecv" without more SDP negotiations. The ontrack event is fired before the SRD promise is resolved, so any modification you do in that event should have completed before the SDP answer is created.